# load bitmap from url the right way

Tags: java, android, bitmap

ok guys need a little help, so I’ve got an app that creates a bitmap images from memory and displays it as an image view, i got to this stage by following the android developer guidelines so it has image scaling, cashing and so on, but now i want to replace the image in memory with one from a website, here is my current code

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight){
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,  int reqWidth, int reqHeight){
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

and this is some code i found to make an image from url

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

i want to know how to implement this to my existing code to incorporate scaling the image to the right resolution to fit my imageView before loading it into memory with the inJustDecodeBounds set to true inorder to avoid outOfMemory exception or is there no longer any need to do this

Comment: first of all recycle all the bitmaps. Secondly once you got an image from server , you stored it in bitmap , now compress this bitmap scale etc. and recycle the previous one. Generally the images we got from server are not much heavy.

Comment: Use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it online i would recommend you using volley imageLoader, the code you are using is downloading. I would recommend you do some research before going into this though, it is a tad bit different that what you would usually do, but once you get it image loading only requires a few lines.On another note if you still wish to download it, change it into bitmap and read it straight from the file.Furthermore to display image from storage doesn't require that much work, an example is at the bottom.

http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/volley-part-3-image-loader

```
 private void loadImageFromStorage(String path, String Name) {
        try {
            File f = new File(path, Name+".jpg");
            double bytes = f.length();
            Bitmap b;
            if(bytes < 1){
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.placeholder);
            }
            else{
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            }
            imageView =  (ImageView).findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```